# python - determining the end of a field reading binary file

Tags: python, null, binary, byte

I'm working with a binary save game file, the file contains a number of fields most are fixed but there are sveral variable length fields which I'm having issues parsing because I don't know the length of them. What I am trying to do is read from a known offset until it reaches either a nullbyte or or returns nothing with that I would then be able to generare the offset for the next field.

The file I'm working with is www.retro-gaming-world.com/SAVE.DAT
the beggining of the field is at 0x8C30 having issues foguring out where it ends though.

I tried doing this with the following code but I don't think I'm going about this right.

```
while catch:
    if "0" in temp2:
            print "found it"
            print temp2
            print hex(infile.tell())
            break
    temp = infile.read(1)
    temp2 += temp
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `'\0'` to represent null character:

```
>>> ord('0')
48
>>> ord('\0')
0
```